# How to post lots of data to laravel database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to submit this data to a database in Laravel. My intention is to submit all at the same time, this is just two rows but I would like to send them together even if it gets to 10 rows I can submit.

```
0: {item: "Electronics", subitem: "Laptop", subitem2: "Hard D", unit: "Length - meter (m)"}
1: {item: "Electronics", subitem: "Laptop", subitem2: "Hard D", unit: "Length - meter (m)"}
```

What I have tried

```
  for ($i = 1; $i < count($request->all()); $i++) {

    $answers[] = [
        'item' => $request->item[$i],
        'subitem' => $request->subitem[$i],
        'subitem2' => $request->subitem2[$i]
    ];
```

I tried to do a for loop using the above code but its not working..got the below error

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert array values into database in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128471/insert-array-values-into-database-in-laravel)

Comment: no does not work..i edited my question to show what i tried now

Comment: You don't try to insert anything with your code, you just put everything in an array and nest. Also what is the request field that holds all this data?

Comment: can u share a sample of what u mean?

Comment: In your question you mention you want to make a batch insert, like insert big data in your database. So i got 2 questions. Where is the insert query to your model and what is the exact request field name that holds all this data? request->all() has no validation and is too general.

Comment: i dont need to do validation. i am sending the date from angular through an api..i just need to dump it into a database

Comment: You **always** need validation, **never** assume data is valid regardless of its origin. Your error is related to `$request->all()` not being what you think it is, debug it. As for mass inserts you can use `Model::insert($data);` or `DB::table('models')->insert($data);`

Comment: since its coming from an api like this postitems($request)...so $request is $data?  or what is $data?

Comment: `print_r($request->all());` check out yourself what it shows. Your data field with all this nested jsons is there, but what is the exact name of the requested field?  Apparently your problem of the question is not in the batch insert, it's in using the loop around all the requests. So basically your question and the error you are showing are not matching with each other.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [item] => Electronics [subitem] => Laptop [subitem2] => Hard D [unit] => Mass - kilogram (kg) ) )
when i print_r i got this

Comment: @shineodigie That loop is useless ... simply because `$answers === $request->all()`. Just `unset()` any excess items. And dump the arrays and you'll see that your code doesn't make much of a difference. I'm still convinced that this is question is a duplicate, when you fail to apply that, it doesn't make it any less of a duplicate.

Comment: yes it is useless but now i am dumping directly like this  DB::table('items')->insertGetId($request->all());    but still i got some errors

Answer (score 2):

So after discussion in comments the solution for what you are trying to achieve can be:

```
foreach ($request->all() as $data){
  Items::insert([
       'item' => $data['item'],
       'subitem' => $data['subitem'],
       'subitem2' => $data['subitem2'],
       'unit' => $data['unit']
  ]);
}
```

If you don't have a model and you literally insert using DB facade then you can do:

```
  DB::table('items')->insert([
       'item' => $data['item'],
       'subitem' => $data['subitem'],
       'subitem2' => $data['subitem2'],
       'unit' => $data['unit']
  ]);
```

But you must build dedicated models.

Also you need to validate your input, `$request->all()` is way too general but this is a suggestion for future improvements and something to keep in mind.

Don't trust the data that the users are sending from the front-end. Back-end should always validate.

Comment: let me try this and get back now

Comment: Glad i helped. If  this is the answer to your question please mark my answer as accepted for future users who have a similar question to yours and read also the notes i made for future improvements to keep in mind.

Comment: i want to mark but it says i cant mark..i think because my account is new

Comment: You can mark it after a few minutes i think, not sure how many though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the laravel documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements

Here is an example of they use for inserting multiple records

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'picard@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'janeway@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
]);
```

Comment: this multiple records are not hard coded..they are coming in from an api