# How to save a JSON Object to MySQL Database in laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

I'm sending data with a ajax call to my laravel server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/data

Laravel Route

```
Route::post('/data',[MainController::class, 'data']);
```

my modle

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('names', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Controller

```
   function data(Request $request)
{

$requestPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");
$object = json_decode($requestPayload);
return ($object);

}
```

Json data i want to save in database

[
{
"name": "Monika khrolia"
},
{
"name": "Ranjana"
},
{
"name": "Ramesh Kumar"
},
{
"name": "Ansuman Biswas"
},
{
"name": "Avijit Ghosh"
},
{
"name": "RAHUL.R"
},
{
"name": "ITI Shitoley"
},
{
"name": "Shubham soni"
},
{
"name": "Awanish Ranjan Rai"
},
{
"name": "Neetu Sharma"
},
{
"name": "Rishi Raj"
},
{
"name": "Priyanka Pokharkar"
},
{
"name": "Chetan Mistry"
},
{
"name": "Chiman Mandali"
},
{
"name": "Raka Yadav"
},
{
"name": "Munna Kumar"
},
{
"name": "kayum ansari"
},
{
"name": "Meraj Ahmad Naqui"
},
{
"name": "Hem Kumar Sharma"
},
{
"name": "Shantangsu Kumar Das"
},
{
"name": "Sreenivasreddy"
},
{
"name": "Mahendra Kumar"
},
{
"name": "Pragya Singhal"
},
{
"name": "Khushboo Talwar"
},
{
"name": "Milan Gayen"
},
{
"name": "Ankita Pandey"
},
{
"name": "Nooruddin Saheb"
},
{
"name": "S.JAHIR HUSSAIN"
},
{
"name": "Arunraj Tamilselvam Harijan"
},
{
"name": "Kunal Murlidhar Kamble"
},
{
"name": "ADYASHA BEJ"
},
{
"name": "Rajendra Yuvraj More"
},
{
"name": "sunil"
},
{
"name": "Sudipta Dey"
},
{
"name": "raman prakash"
},
{
"name": "Harender"
},
{
"name": "Sk Tambirul Islam"
},
{
"name": "Ravi yadav"
},
{
"name": "Maneesh Singh"
},
{
"name": "Navneet Chauhan"
}
]

Comment: This is basic Laravel stuff. Look into "Eloquent Inserts" https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts. And you can probably just grab it from the `$request`.

Comment: show us the code where you are actually saving the data? If it's just the JSON data you want to save then parse it in an array and call a simple eloquent Insert/update method with the data.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49568523/6869708 &
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48128541/6869708

Comment: Thanks @RohitS for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options to deal with this ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements)):

- You can do a bulk insert

```
DB::table( 'names' )->insert( object );
```

or

```
DB::table( 'names' )->insertOrIgnore( object );
```

- Or you can do the save it using the model (in case you want to validate o whatever) ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts)):

```
foreach( $objectList as $objectItem ) 
{
    $name = Name::firstOrNew( [ 'name' => $objectItem->name ]);
    $name->save();
}
```

Best,